# IIS throws 403 for some pages instead of redirecting to https

Tags: asp.net, ssl, webforms, iis-7, redirect

The site I'm working on has a long history, and I'm trying to find where some old settings might be causing IIS to throw undesired 403 errors.

### History

At some point we moved from Windows Authentication to Forms Authentication (Forms and Anonymous Authentication are enabled in IIS, nothing else). When under Windows Authentication, we secured folders in the root directory using the folders' security settings. When we made this switch we cleaned out all folder permissions. The folders (and files) now inherit permissions from their parent directories.

Our Forms Authentication is handled in code (we use our own MembershipProvider and RoleProvider). We also handle redirecting to (and from) SSL pages (most, but not all require it) in code.

### Issue

However, IIS is still intercepting certain http (non-SSL) requests (only for folders that *used to* have extra security settings) and redirecting them to the 403 page. You can see the **correct** `RedirectToLogin` here:

https://www.uxc.com/c/

and the **incorrect**, intercepted redirect here:

http://www.uxc.com/c/

and a page (in a folder not previously secured) **correctly** redirected to https here:

http://www.uxc.com/smr/

and a page (in a folder not previously secured but *now* secured through Forms Authentication) **correctly** redirected to https and then to the login page here:

http://www.uxc.com/rx/

The incorrect redirect occurs whether or not a user is actually logged in (again, using Forms Authentication).

### Steps Taken

- I've narrowed this down to the Error Pages page for the site in IIS. It is running whatever Path (currently /account/Login.aspx) is selected for a 403 status code. If I delete the entry, it still follows the instructions (cached?) even after the app pool is recycled.
- I've double-checked all folder permissions. IUSR has read access to the folder and page being requested (/c/Default.aspx). I can't find any difference in Windows folder permissions between /c/ and /smr/ (all are inherited).
- I've looked through the web.config for any `<authorization>` entries and have found none. (I've even added `<location path="c"><system.web><authorization><allow users="*"/></authorization></system.web></location>` just to see, but it did nothing.
- I've looked for any old web.config files sitting in the specific folders (we used to have these) and found none left sitting around.
- I've placed checks in Global.asax and OnPreInit to verify that none of my code is being reached on these undesired redirects.
- I've entirely deleted one of the offending folders from the server and then republished over top of it. No change.
- I've inspected the `Page` tag for any oddities that might cause it to give the page extra security but found nothing. Here it is for reference:

  ```
  <%@ Page EnableViewState="false" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Normal.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="(censored).c.Default" Title="Ux Consulting (censored)" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" %>
  ```

How can I make IIS perform the same in my /c/ folder as it does in my /smr/ folder? I want it to allow things to reach my code so that I can redirect to SSL or do `RedirectToLogin` manually.

Comment: View my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884117/403-forbidden-error-in-public-folder-when-i-try-redirection/39892798?noredirect=1 View updated ***web.config***