# 403 Forbidden error in Public Folder when I try redirection

Tags: asp.net, path, redirect, http-status-code-403

I have ASP.NET site.

I can access to the public page, it's OK:

> http://mysite/MyPublicFolder/index.htm

But I get **403 error** when I try access to the folder:

> http://mysite/MyPublicFolder/

MyPublicFolder contains **index.htm**.

I want *Not allow users to browse directory, only Access to all pages in Folder*.

We have the following error:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

```
<location path="/MyPublicFolder">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
```

I am using IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**: *web.config*

Note: ***v1*** is my **Public Folder**

```
<location path="v1">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="Config\system.web.authorization.allow.config" />
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <add value="index.htm"/>
        </files>
      </defaultDocument>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Found">
          <add wildcard="*" destination="/v1/index.htm" />
        </httpRedirect>
    </system.webServer>

  </location>

    <location path="v1/index.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: Do you want to allow your users to browse your directory?

Comment: I want *Not allow users to browse directory, only Access to all pages in Folder*. MyPublicFolder contains **index.htm**.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that is in my mind is default document. Do you have it set to 'index.htm'? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623681/setting-default-webpage-in-iis-7-5) is a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit confusing. You are saying that you can open `http://mysite/MyPublicFolder/index.htm` what means that you have already got an access to all the pages located in this folder. I can just guess that you expect to get a redirect to `index.htm` file when you access a folder. Check out Default Document section in the IIS manager and make sure that `index.htm` is there.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like there are a lot of useless configuration in your `web.config` file. Change it to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="v1">
    <system.web>
      <authorization configSource="Config\system.web.authorization.allow.config" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Now if you access your `v1` folder it should automatically show you content of your `index.htm` file.